# How to set a different theme when the site is on maintenaince mode?

Tags: theming

Hi i am searching for a way to change the active theme when the site is on maintenaince mode (Drupal 7), can you help me? thanks in advice

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no way to set active theme while on maintenance mode, but you can change the way site looks.

For that to happen in your local site there is [`/modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!maintenance-page.tpl.php/7) available.

You can overwrite as you need by pasting this into your theme directory.

Then in settings.php you need to set

```
$conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'ThemeName'
```

Comment: I don't think $conf['maintenance_theme] works in D7, see https://drupal.org/node/903042